# Inequality $x - \sqrt{x^2 + 1} > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is how I solved this inequality:
$$ x - \sqrt{x^2 + 1} > 0$$
$$ x > \sqrt{x^2 + 1} $$
$$x < 0 \implies x^2 < x^2 + 1 \iff 1 > 0 \implies\text{inequality holds for all x}$$
$$x\geq 0 \implies x^2 > x ^2 +1 \iff 1 < 0 \implies \text{inequality doesn't hold }$$

The thing is that this shouldn't hold for any x. Can somebody explain why is my procedure wrong.

Comment: @player3236 because we square x and if it is negative then the inequality turns around... doesn't it ?

Comment: I deleted my comment because I thought there were typos. Either there are a mountain of typos, or $x < 0 \implies x^2 >x^2+1$ does not make sense. I am referring to the latter conclusions: $x^2 > x^2 + 1 \iff 1>0$ and $x^2< x^2+1 \iff 1<0$.

Comment: @player3236 thank you, I will repair the question

Comment: "Squaring" neither preserve inequality nor flip it; whether it is flipped or not depends on their absolute values. Consider the examples $-2 < 1$ and $-1 < 2$, which gives $4 > 1$ and $1 < 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x < 0 \implies x^2 < x^2 + 1 \iff 1 > 0 \implies\text{inequality holds for all x}$$
I want to try and show why this conclusion of yours is wrong.  Let's see if we can go back to the starting inequality from this.

But first notice that a small square shape has a small side and a large square shape has a large side. This is same as saying  $\sqrt{t}$  function is increasing.

Since $x^2$ and $x^2+1$ are nonnegative,

$1\gt 0 \implies x^2 \lt x^2+1 \implies \sqrt{x^2} \lt \sqrt{x^2+1}\implies |x| \lt \sqrt{x^2+1} \implies x\lt \sqrt{x^2+1}$.

This is not the starting inequality. You got it wrong because you're falsely assuming that squaring both sides of an inequality flips the inequality depending on the polarity of sides. Please look at @player3236 comment at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is false.In fact is the oppposite.

Indeed, For any real number $x$, $x^2+1>x^2\ge0$, so (since $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$ is increasing on $[0,+\infty)$) $\sqrt{x^2+1}>\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. But $|x|\ge x$, so $\sqrt{x^2+1}>x$, whence $$x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0.$$

Comment: @PeterSzilas it is increasing on $[0,+\infty)$ and both $x^2+1$ and $x^2$ are non negative

Answer (score 1):

The proposed inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
x > \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}
\end{align*}

If $x \leq 0$, clearly there is no solution because the LHS is nonpositive and the RHS is positive.

Let us assume that $x > 0$. In this case, due to the AM-GM inequality, one has that
\begin{align*}
x > \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} > 2|x| = 2x \Rightarrow x < 0
\end{align*}
which contradicts our assumption.

Thus the proposed inequality has no solution.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1)$x \le 0;$ the inequality is false.

2)$x>0;$

Assume the inequality is true.

Multiply both sides by $x+\sqrt{x^2+1} >0.$

Then

$(x-\sqrt{x^2+1})(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})>0;$

$x^2-x^2-1>0;$

$-1>0,$ a contradiction.